# Restrict the size of contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I'm building a program where you can insert copied HTML from your Webbrowser into the program and then edit it by using a contenteditable div tag, but the copied HTML overflows the div and doesn't apply the style in relative to my div but to the whole screen, is there a way to prevent that?

```js
document.getElementById("HTMLMD").contentEditable = html;
```

```css
#container-HTMLMD {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
}
#HTMLMD {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-HTMLMD">
  <div id="HTMLMD" spellcheck="false"></div>
</div>
```

Result (the top bar should only take half of the width as the other elements):
[image]

Comment: Change `100vh` to `50vh`?

Comment: oh I see my code was unclear, the #container-HTMLMD div is the child of a div which has `width: 50vw`, I want the contenteditable div to just take up half the width of the screen as all the other elements in the div but the google search bar

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:
I inspected the html contents and saw that the overflowing items were items with `position: absolute` and `position: fixed`, I fixed the problem by first setting `#HTMLMD { position: relative }` which fixed the problem for the items with `position: absolute`, then I wrote the JS script:

```
let children = inner.getElementsByTagName("*");
children.forEach((e) => {
  if (e.style.position === "fixed") e.style.position = "absolute";
});
```

which sets all items with `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`, which is definitly not an optimal solution but it works in my case.